# MacBook Pro 2020 Fan Issues

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, google-chrome, cpu, temperature

I recently purchased a MacBook Pro 2020 13" (1.4 GHz, 8GB Ram, i5). For some reason, when I open Chrome and watch Twitch my computers fans turn on and go crazy. After opening Activity Monitor, I noticed that Google Chrome Helper (Renderer) uses around 50-80% of my CPU.

Also, sometimes when I run code on my MacBook Pro, the fans turn on when the program is compiling/running but slow down a few minutes after terminating the program. Also, when watching Twice on Safari, the fans don't come on. However, around 50-60% of the CPU is still being used.

Should I be concerned about the CPU usage (I am nervous because I only recently purchased the laptop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be concerned about the CPU usage (I am nervous because I only recently purchased the laptop)? I am nervous because I only recently purchased the laptop)

Nervous?  No.

From a hardware (damage) perspective, your Mac and the CPU itself is designed to protect itself from overheating.  It will kick in the fans, then throttle things back and finally, if it must, it will shut itself off.  Your risk of doing damage to your machine is virtually nil.

From a software perspective, I wouldn't worry either.  It sounds like your Mac is doing what it's supposed to do which is turn on the fans during high intensity CPU activity (compiling code) or watching video (GPU).  That said, I would probably look at something else besides Chrome as it's a known resource hog and not very "kind" to memory or CPU utilization.

It's also important to remember that the 13" MacBook Pro doesn't have a discrete GPU so it's the CPU that's going to be doing all of the graphic rendering and it will use up to 1.5GB of RAM as video memory ([Intel Integrated Graphics Chipset](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/283602/119271)).  So, if you're compiling code **and** watching HD or 4K videos simultaneously, you could be maxing out your hardware.

So, it is possible you *undersized* your Mac for your needs, so from a *value* perspective, I would defiantly look at that.  If you're still within your return period, it's something you should make a priority to evaluate.